# How to redirect the file path in react-native

Tags: react-native

[image]

I have no idea why Webstorm is not finding my pictures all ways to import the pictures but The simulator are telling me that none of my files exist

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about this. Editors generally don't suggest images while writing paths.

Just remove the import statement and directly access the image in the Image tag.

like this,

```
<Image source={require('./src/resources/images/Logo.png')}/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man , was trying to find the solution more then 2 hours puhhhhhhh

Comment: My pleasure, just don't forget to upvote and mark as answer. ;)